# One unnecessary select statement in TokenGuard

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am using TokenGuard for all the database related requests through JQuery in Laravel 5.4

**Once the user is logged in...I am fetching the user profile using below method.**

```
public function ViewProfile() {
    $user = \Auth::guard("api")->user();
    $Data = [
        "FirstName"     =>  $user->FirstName,
        "LastName"      =>  $user->LastName
    ];
    return  \Response::json([
        'Status'    =>  true,
        'Data'      =>  $Data,
    ], 200);
}
```

**Below is the POST method Url being sent to Server to fetch the data using above method**

> http://localhost:1234/public/api/v1/apiviewprofile?api_token=598bbba095bdd1598bbba095bf1

When I printed the select statements being issued on fetching the user details...I saw there were two select statements below.

```
[2017-08-10 02:37:05] local.INFO: select * from `tbluser` where `UserID` = ? limit 1  
[2017-08-10 02:37:05] local.INFO: select * from `tbluser` where `api_token` = ? limit 1
```

**Question**

I can understand that when I send POST request using TokenGuard...it first validate token....so that time it goes to database. So second select statement is fine. But, where is Laravel 5.4 using first select statement?

Answer (score 0):

The second statement is indeed run after you call `->user()` on the guard returned from `Auth::guard()`, inside the guard's contained [UserProvider](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Auth/UserProviderInterface.html#method_retrieveByCredentials) implementation.

The first statement is unlikely to be triggered from the code that you provided. I suspect that it has something to do with some middleware that you have on the route using the `ViewProfile()` action.

Maybe the query is performed even before a redirect to that route, after you've successfully authenticated the user? (the first query is exactly a user authentication query).

Redirects can complete within a fraction of a second, and since the logs show the time in 1-second precision, it is impossible to tell how much time is exactly in between. Unless you are certain that no redirect takes place at all, it is hard to tell if these two queries execute within the same Laravel container lifecycle at all.